# Code Block with table not showing on Mailchimp

Tags: html-table, html-email, mailchimp

I am building an email template on Mailchimp using code blocks in some parts. I have created a seemingly simple table which does show on the visual composer but does not show when I click on Preview or Test.

This is a standalone block, so I don't think I need to insert table anywhere but within a div element. After previewing the entire template and returning to the visual composer, the table disappears but does re-appear after clicking on the element below.

[image]

Is there any reason why this happens?

```html
<div class="mcnTextContent" style="margin-left:64px; margin-right:64px">
<table style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-color: #1F1F1F; width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="line-height: 0px !important; padding-bottom: 48px !important;" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td width="33%"><span style="font-size: 10px !important; vertical-align: middle;"> </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold;">Year Launch</span>
<div style="line-height: 8px;">&nbsp;</div>
<span style="font-size: 16px;">2020<br/>UCITs version - 2015</span></td>
<td colspan="2"><span style="font-size: 10px !important; vertical-align: middle;"> </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold;">Assets Under Management</span>
<div style="line-height: 8px;">&nbsp;</div>
<span style="font-size: 16px;">USD $1B strategy<br/>UCITs version - SD $0.4B</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="line-height: 0px !important; padding-bottom: 20px !important;" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="33%"><span style="font-size: 10px !important; vertical-align: middle;"> </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold;">Performance 2020</span>
<div style="line-height: 8px;">&nbsp;</div>
<span style="font-size: 16px;">5.49%<sup>2</sup></span></td>
<td width="33%"><span style="font-size: 10px !important; vertical-align: middle;"> </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold;">YTD Performance</span>
<div style="line-height: 8px;">&nbsp;</div>
<span style="font-size: 16px;">0.50%<sup>1</sup></span></td>
<td width="33%"><span style="font-size: 10px !important; vertical-align: middle;"> </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold;">Yield-to-Worst</span>
<div style="line-height: 8px;">&nbsp;</div>
<span style="font-size: 16px;">8.95%<sup>2</sup></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="line-height: 0px !important; padding-bottom: 20px !important;" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="33%"><span style="font-size: 10px !important; vertical-align: middle;"> </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold;">Duration</span>
<div style="line-height: 8px;">&nbsp;</div>
<span style="font-size: 16px;">4 years<sup>1</sup></span></td>
<td width="33%"><span style="font-size: 10px !important; vertical-align: middle;"> </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold;">3-year Volatility</span>
<div style="line-height: 8px;">&nbsp;</div>
<span style="font-size: 16px;">7.23%<sup>2</sup></span></td>
<td width="33%"><span style="font-size: 10px !important; vertical-align: middle;"> </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold;"># of Positions</span>
<div style="line-height: 8px;">&nbsp;</div>
<span style="font-size: 16px;">144<sup>3</sup></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="line-height: 0px !important; padding-bottom: 20px !important;" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="33%"><span style="font-size: 10px !important; vertical-align: middle;"> </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold;">Gross Yield (USD)</span>
<div style="line-height: 8px;">&nbsp;</div>
<span style="font-size: 16px;">442%<sup>2</sup></span></td>
<td width="33%"><span style="font-size: 10px !important; vertical-align: middle;"> </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold;">MTM Yield (USD)</span>
<div style="line-height: 8px;">&nbsp;</div>
<span style="font-size: 16px;">45%<sup>2</sup></span></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="line-height: 0px !important; padding-bottom: 20px !important;" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-size: 12px !important; line-height: 16px;" colspan="3"><sup>1</sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;Source: Morningstar Direct March, 5th, 2021 (HI USD shareclass).<br/> <sup>2</sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;Source: TwentyFour, Bloomberg; February 28th, 2021.<br/> <sup>3</sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;This is now credit issuers only so it excludes ABS and Government (total credit positions = 271). Source: TwentyFour Bloomberg Feb 28th 2021.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="line-height: 0px !important; padding-bottom: 20px !important;" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px;">Ratings &amp; Awards</span></td>
<td width="33%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="line-height: 0px !important; padding-bottom: 20px !important;" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right: 40px;" colspan="2"><span style="font-size:20px;">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span><div style="line-height: 4px;">&nbsp;</div>
<span style="font-weight: bold;">Morningstar</span>
<div style="line-height: 8px;">&nbsp;</div>
<span style="font-size: 16px;">This fund has been awarded.</span></td>
<td style="background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/Jkd3npD/Untitled-1-copy.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 189px 117px; width: 189px; height: 117px;" colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="line-height: 0px !important; padding-bottom: 48px !important;" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: In email, what you see is *not* what you get. I'd guess there are some internal styles that are conflicting, but also, depending on what you're testing on, there's some problems there too. You shouldn't use inline !important, for example, because Outlook desktop will ignore that style. And I would wrap it in a table, putting the margins on the outermost `<td>`, rather than a div. Look for conflicts in styles, and see if you can change your approach so you don't have to use !important inline. (Also might help to post entire code, `<head>` included)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the issue was with the emoji  I used. For some reason Mailchimp didn't allow the table to render correctly.